# why ARM instruction address is not align on my ARM Environment?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, arm, thumb

My ARM Envrionment is

root@linaro-developer:~# uname -a
Linux linaro-developer 3.2.0 #7 SMP Thu Feb 28 16:20:18 PST 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

And my assembly is

```
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
        .code 32
        #Thumb-Mode on
        add r6, pc, #1
        bx r6
        .code 16
        sub r4, r4, r4
        mov r0, r4
        ldr r2, =0x80047dbc
        blx r2
        ldr r2, =0x80047a0c
        blx r2
```

However, When I'm trying to debug using gdb, pc is not going to sub r4, r4, r4
gdb state is

```
(gdb) x/3i $pc
=> 0x83c8: add r6, pc, #1
   0x83cc:        bx r6     ;r6 = 0x83d1
   0x83d0: stcne 11, cr1, [r0], #-144 ; 0xffffff70
(gdb) x/3i 0x83d1
   0x83d1: subs r4, r4, r4
   0x83d3: adds r0, r4, #0
   0x83d5: ldr r2, [pc, #4] ; (0x83dc)
```

subs r4, r4, r4 address is 0x83d1
0x83d1 is not aligned

Why my assembly code is located at unaligned address?

Comment: pc is going to 0x83d0 and then 0x83d2 (Thumb) However, I want to execute 'subs r4, r4, r4'. What should I do? When I execute my assembly code, it happen 'Segment Fault'

Comment: What is the address of the access triggering the fault?

Comment: (gdb) x/3i $pc
=> 0x83c8: add r6, pc, #1
   0x83cc: bx r6
   0x83d0: stcne 11, cr1, [r0], #-144 ; 0xffffff70
(gdb) ni
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
0x000083cc in ?? ()
(gdb) si
0x000083d0 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/3i $pc
=> 0x83d0: stcne 11, cr1, [r0], #-144 ; 0xffffff70
   0x83d4: ldrmi r4, [r0, r1, lsl #20]
   0x83d8: ldrmi r4, [r0, r1, lsl #20]
(gdb) ni
0x000083d2 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/3i $pc
=> 0x83d2: bmi 0x4f45a
   0x83d6: bmi 0x5a21e
   0x83da: ldcvc 7, cr4, [r12, #576]! ; 0x240
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x80047dbc in ?? ()

Comment: Sorry Look this trace is so hard :(

Comment: Oh, 0x80047dbc is prepare_kernel_cred address. 
Why this address is not mapped? 
I check this address using `grep _cred /proc/kallsyms` command

Comment: Are you sure it is valid to enter the kernel that way?  It sounds a bit suspect, so it would not be surprising if it were not mapped *for userspace*.  Also "x" is not a trace, but rather an examine command, and you should be editing the results into your question rather than posting them as comments.

Comment: Why bother writing assembly in thumb in first place? Unlike the 32-bit ARM mode, there isn't much of a gain writing thumb assembly.

Answer (score 3):

A (full) ARM processor can execute instructions in either ARM or Thumb execution state - roughly speaking, the difference between the versatility of a full 32-bit instruction word, or the code-size efficiency of a more limited 16-bit one.

When branching to an address contained in a register, you have the ability to set the ARM or Thumb state with the LSB of the register contents, which appears to be what the code you are debugging is doing - branching to 0x83d1 will set Thumb state, but the actual address of the target instruction will be 0x83d0, which is 16-bit aligned.

In contrast, if branching to an immediate offset, you do not have the ability to set the mode with the LSB, but can instead choose between B/BL which retain state, or BX/BLX which toggle it.

Note that some smaller ARM cores intended for embedded usage *only* support Thumb mode, and cannot execute ARM instructions.

Comment: Note that the PC register itself always contains the correctly aligned address (and you'll get a fault if it doesn't) - the lsb of _the value written_ to the PC in an interworking instruction is what matters. The actual status ends up in the T bit of the CPSR. Of course, how gdb chooses to represent things may be another matter.

Comment: The code is located at 0x83d0, not 0x83d1 (though your debugger is helpfully displaying it at the alignment masked address derived from your entry).  Is it not working?  What happens if you trace it?